# Circular prime, help finding the mistake, C++

Tags: c++, primes

Spent and hour trying to find a mistake, didn't succeed :(
Solving Euler's problem: http://projecteuler.net/problem=35
Seems that my head is not working at the moment

Code is not optimized, sorry for that (What am I doing wrong here?)
The right answer is 55, my program gives me 22

```
#include "euler.hpp"
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    euler::prime_generator<euler::eratosthenes_sieve> gen;
    gen.range(0, 1000000);
    unsigned c = 0; // number of circular primes
    unsigned p = 0; // number of primes (test)
    unsigned prime;
    while(prime = gen.nextPrime()) {
        p++;
        bool ok = true;
        std::vector<unsigned> pv = euler::number2vector(prime);
        if(pv.size() > 1) {

            bool cont = false;
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < pv.size(); ++i) {
                if(pv[i] % 2 == 0) { cont = true; break; }
            }
            if(cont) continue;
            std::sort(pv.begin(), pv.end());

            do {
                if(!gen.isPrime(euler::array2number(&pv[0], pv.size()))) {
                    // was desperate and made this
                    if(euler::isPrime(euler::array2number(&pv[0], pv.size()))) {
                        std::cout << prime << " -> " << euler::array2number(&pv[0], pv.size()) << std::endl;
                    }
                    else ok = false;
                    break;
                }
            } while(std::next_permutation(pv.begin(), pv.end()));

        }
        if(ok) {
            //std::cout << prime << std::endl;
            c++;
        }
        //std::cout << prime << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << p << " -> " << c << std::endl;

    euler::pause();
}
```

Several external functions I use

```
// in class
void range(unsigned lower_bound, unsigned upper_bound) {
    m_lower_bound = lower_bound;
    primes.resize(upper_bound - lower_bound + 1, true);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 2 - lower_bound; ++i) primes[i] = false;
    for(unsigned i = 2; i <= sqrt(upper_bound - lower_bound); ++i) {
        if(primes[i]) {
            for(unsigned j = i*i; j <= upper_bound; j += i) {
                primes[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
// in the same class
bool isPrime(unsigned number) {
    return primes[number - m_lower_bound];
}

// in the same class
unsigned nextPrime() {
    for(; next <= m_upper_bound; ++next) {
        if(isPrime(next)) return next++ + m_lower_bound;
    }
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
T array2number(T * begin, unsigned length) {
    T number = 0;
    unsigned m = 1;
    while(length--) {
        number += begin[length] * m;
        m *= 10;
    }
    return number;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> number2vector(T number) {
    unsigned l = number_length(number);
    std::vector<T> vec(l);
    while(l--) {
        vec[l] = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return vec;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try to narrow down your code to what function you think is going wrong, most people aren't going to read through your entire code.

Comment: yea, I know. But I rechecked every function. I would have never posted here if I wasn't that desperate :( But thanks for answering

Comment: the problem is how long your code is, add small cout statements throughout each function to watch what it is doing. It's tedious work but it'll help debug your program

Comment: I removed all couts before I posted the code here. It was like twice bigger. but thanks again

Comment: The Questions at project Euler do most of the time contain the solution for a smaller problem space (for your problem it lists the circular primes till 100). Does your code work for that simple case? If not, check which number are returned. If there are wrong numbers, use a debugger to find out what happens in those cases. If there are some missing, debug what happens for those.

Comment: My code works fine with primes till 100, of course I checked it :) Thanks

Comment: @AleksandrBelkin please list the list the 22 numbers you get so far.

Comment: @kakTuZ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 31, 37, 71, 73, 79, 97, 113, 131, 199, 311, 337, 373, 733, 919, 991

Comment: The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer, not to update your question and its title. If none of the existing answers solve your problem, feel free to post an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved many times on SO.  Search for "[c++] prime euler".

Evidence is given by the terminating condition of the `for` loop:

```
sqrt(upper_bound - lower_bound)
```

I can't find the definition of `primes[]` in your post.  The `range` function accesses it, but it is not supplied via parameters nor is the `primes` array declared within the function.

You can get a lot of information by searching SO and the web.  Try that before posting.

Comment: Yes, I know where to find the right solution, I also know how to solve the task the other way which works. The question is WHY this code is not working, cuz everything seems pretty fine to me.
lower_bound does nothing, i didn't finished the code yet.
primes[] is a vector. I pasted the class method, so the code isn't that big and long

Comment: @AleksandrBelkin the place to ask for your specific code to be reviewed, is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @WillNess Thanks, didn't know that! Will post there next time

Comment: in 1 year there might not be "many times on SO". Please always try to give some sources, personally I get seriously frustrated when I get to a forum and the first thing I read is "search elsewhere"

Comment: @Default: As I said there have been sooo many Euler prime number posts.  I used Google, "stackoverflow euler prime numbers" and this is what I got: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=3&gs_mss=stackoverflow%20c%2B%2B%20e&tok=DQ7YUjydDC4PoS5HMR127g&cp=30&gs_id=w3&xhr=t&q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+euler+primes&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+euler+primes&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=8c4d5c05325012e4&bpcl=38897761&biw=1280&bih=892